# How to reproduce System.DmlException: Update failed

Tags: trigger

HOw to reproduce this trigger error

> First exception on row 2; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Comment: Please explain your question bit more. It is not clear. If you want to run trigger  then just make condition again like insert record or update record.

Comment: I think the error is coming while updating the records. In error statement it is mentioned that MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified. But I don't know How to reproduce this error.

Comment: `update new Account(Name='test');` should give the same error.

Comment: also  have some debug Log

Comment: 11:35:36.254 (4254951905)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|AccountTrigger on Account trigger event AfterUpdate for [0017000000ORaxc, 0017000000u8gEp]
11:35:36.255 (4255626351)|DML_END|[118]
11:35:36.255 (4255848966)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[118]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 2; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Comment: so try to update your trigger object record i think you will get same error or you can check the code(if not managed Package part). and you will easily find the problem and will be able to solve it

Comment: But in trigger I am not having any After Update event .I have trigger TriggerSIMGeocodeAccount on Account (before update, before delete,after insert)

Comment: If you want to know why your code is throwing that error then provide the code that is causing the error and show where the error is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forum is to finding an answer for an issue, but this is how to make an issue. Anyway you can recreate by just performing `update` action on an sObject which doesn't have the `Id` field.

```
Account acct = new Account(Name='my account');
update acct;
```

This will lead you into the specified exception. It's cleat that you can not update a record which has not the `Id` field. To perform the update action, first the data should be there in the database.

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a record and call it like so

```
update someObj;
```

then Salesforce will find that record in the Database and update it. However, if `someObj` does not yet have an Id, Salesforce cannot find it, so it doesn't know what record to update. Hence, you'll get

> MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

An example of this would be

```
Account someObj = new Account(Name='Some Name');
update someObj;
```

If you want to update if the record exists, and insert if it does not already exist, you could use `upsert`. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm

Comment: Thanks to u also but I can not mark your answer.I have only one chance

Comment: Yes, you can only pick one. Usually you would pick the best answer, or, if they both work, the first answer. That would be my answer in this case, but it doesn't matter. Good that it solved your problem! Cheers :-)